# Stack/Arithmetic expressions bug

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, stack

I have a bug and wrong answer in this code, [image: Image with the output]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


struct Stack
{
    int top;
    unsigned capacity;
    int* array;
};

struct Stack* createStack(unsigned capacity)
{
    struct Stack* stack = (struct Stack*)
        malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));

    if (!stack)
        return NULL;

    stack->top = -1;
    stack->capacity = capacity;

    stack->array = (int*)malloc(stack->capacity *
        sizeof(int));

    return stack;
}
int isEmpty(struct Stack* stack)
{
    return stack->top == -1;
}
char peek(struct Stack* stack)
{
    return stack->array[stack->top];
}
char pop(struct Stack* stack)
{
    if (!isEmpty(stack))
        return stack->array[stack->top--];
    return '$';
}
void push(struct Stack* stack, char op)
{
    stack->array[++stack->top] = op;
}

int isOperand(char ch)
{
    return (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9');
}

int Prec(char ch)
{
    switch (ch)
    {
    case '+':
    case '-':
        return 1;

    case '*':
    case '/':
        return 2;

    case '^':
        return 3;
    }
    return -1;
}

int infixToPostfix(char* exp)
{
    int i, k;

    struct Stack* stack = createStack(strlen(exp));
    if (!stack)
        return -1;

    for (i = 0, k = -1; exp[i]; ++i)
    {
        if (isOperand(exp[i]))
            exp[++k] = exp[i];
        else if (exp[i] == '(')
            push(stack, exp[i]);
        else if (exp[i] == ')')
        {
            while (!isEmpty(stack) && peek(stack) != '(')
                exp[++k] = pop(stack);
            if (!isEmpty(stack) && peek(stack) != '(')
                return -1;
            else
                pop(stack);
        }
        else
        {
            while (!isEmpty(stack) &&
                Prec(exp[i]) <= Prec(peek(stack)))
                exp[++k] = pop(stack);
            push(stack, exp[i]);
        }

    }

    while (!isEmpty(stack))
        exp[++k] = pop(stack);

    exp[++k] = '\0';
    printf("Reverse Polish Notation:\n");

    char str[1000];

    strcpy(str, exp);

    for (i = 0; str[i]; i++)
    {
        printf("%c ", str[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int evaluatePostfix(char* exp)
{
    struct Stack* stack = createStack(strlen(exp));
    int i;

    if (!stack) return -1;

    for (i = 0; exp[i]; ++i)
    {
        if (isdigit(exp[i]))
            push(stack, exp[i] - '0');
        else
        {
            int val1 = pop(stack);
            int val2 = pop(stack);
            switch (exp[i])
            {
            case '+': push(stack, val2 + val1); break;
            case '-': push(stack, val2 - val1); break;
            case '*': push(stack, val2 * val1); break;
            case '/': push(stack, val2 / val1); break;
            }
        }
    }
    return pop(stack);
}


int main()
{
    char exp[1000];
    scanf("%s", exp);
    printf("Expression:\n%s\n", exp);

    infixToPostfix(exp);
    printf("Result: \n%d", evaluatePostfix(exp));
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Here is the idea of the program**

Objective: To implement an algorithm for parsing an arithmetic expression. Allowed operations in an expression: +, -, *, /, numeric literals, parentheses to set priority.

Input format

Input data:

As an input for the algorithm, a single line is given - the written arithmetic expression.

Output format

Result:

The result of the algorithm is the calculated value of the input expression. In addition to the result, it is necessary to display the record of the original expression in postfix notation (reverse Polish notation).

Comment: You're dividing by 0.

Comment: Looks like a division by zero.  When you evaluate .... 5 0 /  you pop a zero as val1 then 5 as val2 next you evaluate val2 / val1.

Answer (score 0):

The crash is caused by a divide-by-0 in this code:
`case '/': push(stack, val2 / val1); break;`

As mentioned, the loop is popping a 5 and then 0 off the stack and dividing them.

The underlying issue with the code is that you are processing the operands char-by-char instead of operand-by-operand. In your example, the expression generated by infixToPostfix is "1002100*50/+". This is not workable, because we cannot tell that the original numbers were 100, 2, 100, because there are no spaces between them. You can fix this by making infixToPostfix add a space after every number. This would also require us to build the postfix expression in a separate string since k can now overtake i:

```
int infixToPostfix(char* exp)
{
    int i, k;
    char postfixExp[strlen(exp)];

    struct Stack* stack = createStack(strlen(exp));
    if (!stack)
        return -1;

    for (i = 0, k = -1; exp[i]; ++i)
    {
        if(i != 0 && !isOperand(exp[i]) && isOperand(exp[i-1]))
        {
            //if this digit is not a number but the last digit was, insert a space
            postfixExp[++k] = ' ';
        }
        
        if (isOperand(exp[i]))
            postfixExp[++k] = exp[i];
        else if (exp[i] == '(')
            push(stack, exp[i]);
        else if (exp[i] == ')')
        {
            while (!isEmpty(stack) && peek(stack) != '(')
                postfixExp[++k] = pop(stack);
            if (!isEmpty(stack) && peek(stack) != '(')
                return -1;
            else
                pop(stack);
        }
        else
        {
            while (!isEmpty(stack) &&
                Prec(exp[i]) <= Prec(peek(stack)))
                postfixExp[++k] = pop(stack);
            push(stack, exp[i]);
        }
    }

    while (!isEmpty(stack))
        postfixExp[++k] = pop(stack);

    postfixExp[++k] = '\0';
    strcpy(exp, postfixExp);
    printf("Reverse Polish Notation:\n");


    for (i = 0; exp[i]; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", exp[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This code (untested, use at your own risk) should output the string "100 2 100 *50 /+". evaluatePostfix now needs to be modified to read this string and accumulate digits until it reaches a space. Rather than pushing/popping individual chars onto the stack, it needs to read an entire operand and push that int onto the stack.